# Using 'as' is giving two compile errors

Tags: javascript, typescript, compiler-errors

I am not sure what is wrong (if anything, because it compiles fine, but when it does compile I get the following errors:

> src/Net/Route.ts(35,77): error TS1005: ',' expected.
>   src/Net/Route.ts(35,80): error TS1005: '=' expected.

The two `^` mark the location of where the errors are:

```
let target: HTMLElement = document.querySelector(targetStr) as HTMLElement;
                                                           ^  ^
```

Am I doing something wrong, or is this a compiler bug? I have written code like this before and have never gotten this error. Then again I am using a new version of TypeScript (2.0.3).

Answer (score 0):

> Then again I am using a new version of TypeScript (2.0.3).

Actually you are probably using an *old* version of the compiler. This one works fine : http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=let%20target%3A%20HTMLElement%20%3D%20document.querySelector(%22asdf%22)%20as%20HTMLElement%3B